# UDF gives different result compared to actual formula in excel direct

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I have a formula in excel that is as follows:

```
=Round(33.468*(Log(Log(M+0.8)))+23.097;2)
```

as i have a large amount of data and need to use this frequently i created a UDF based off this formula as follows:

```
Function visco(M)

visco = Round(33.468 * (Log(Log(M + 0.8))) + 23.097, 2)

End Function
```

however when i plug in a value for M the value in each is different, the excel formula directly in the cell is correct whereas the UDF result is wrong.

I am unsure what has happened here if anyone is able to explain

thanks

Comment: Neither `VBA.Round` nor `VBA.Log` are the same as the worksheet functions. If you want to get the same result, you could use `WorksheetFunction.Round` and `WorksheetFuncction.Log`  Examine `HELP` for those functions to help understand the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Log` in vba does not equal `LOG` in the worksheet.  in vba it is Log(e) not Log(10).

Either use worksheet function:

```
visco = Round(33.468 * (Application.Log(Application.Log(M + 0.8))) + 23.097, 2)
```

or divide by the log of the base desired.

```
visco = Round(33.468 * ((Log((Log(M + 0.8) / Log(10#))) / Log(10#))) + 23.097, 2)
```

Comment: Don't forget `Round()` also !  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265926/round-function-in-excel-worksheet-function-vs-vba