# 2-factor lookup with an approximate match in Excel (not 365 version)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, index-match

I have a timecard-style task where I need to analyze a large group of data to evaluate maximum/minimum occupancy for a controlled-entry worksite.  I get data in a bulk raw format.  There are many columns, but the pertinent ones are Name, Badge scan time, and scan location (east/west, in/out).

My task is to construct a lookup that finds the last time an employee scanned their badge and determine if it was in or out of the controlled space.

I sort the data ascending by scan time, and I can both find the combination of a selected employee and the scan-location (general space vs controlled space) and scan-type (in/out) using concatenation.
Independently, I can find the last scan time of a badge based on selected inputs (I have fields for year, month, day, and time of day) using the following formula:

```
=INDEX(BadgeTime,MATCH(TRUNC(DATE($B$3,$C$3,$D$3)+$F5,6),BadgeTime,1),1)
```

I added a helper column in the raw data that truncates the badge scan time to match my lookup.  (That helper column is the named range "BadgeTime" in the formula).

My question is how do I combine the two?  Every version of two-factor lookup I have found so far uses (needs) exact match because they all use some version of concatenation (or they create 2 arrays of true/false, force it to 1/0, and compare).  But I need to find the closest (approximate) time of a specific (exact) name and place.

[All the examples I've found are along the lines of "how to look up name and month to find sales data".  When my version would be "how to look up name and sales target data and find the last month that person met the target"].

I found this formula from an answer in a different question and am curious if I can somehow incorporate something similar:

```
=MAX(($A$2:$A$101*100+$B$1:$CW$1<B103)*($B$2:$CW$101=TargetValue)*($A$2:$A$101*100+$B$1:$CW$1))
```

This is from the first answer in the question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220966/lookup-data-in-excel)

Based on feedback (thank you), here is a table of sample data.
Example 1: Lookup for Harmony Song on 2021-11-01 at 06:45 would find Controlled IN at 44501.275115.

Example 2: Lookup for Harmony Song on 2021-11-01 at 06:30 would skip the Lobby IN and Lobby OUT and find Controlled OUT at 44501.269965.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Full Name** | **Employee No.** | **Badge Date/Time** | **BadgeTime** | **Location** |
| John Smith | 552510 | 2021-11-01 05:31:02 | 44501.229884 | Lobby IN |
| Matthew Doe | 321321 | 2021-11-01 05:37:57 | 44501.234687 | Lobby IN |
| Matthew Doe | 321321 | 2021-11-01 05:40:22 | 44501.236365 | Office |
| Matthew Doe | 321321 | 2021-11-01 05:41:27 | 44501.237118 | Office |
| Daryl Strawberry | 311223 | 2021-11-01 05:59:26 | 44501.249606 | Lobby IN |
| Jerry Markson | 561100 | 2021-11-01 06:07:26 | 44501.255162 | Lobby IN |
| Donna Matthews | 571050 | 2021-11-01 06:13:41 | 44501.259502 | Lobby IN |
| Terry McNeil | 255103 | 2021-11-01 06:13:51 | 44501.259618 | Lobby IN |
| Terrance Covington | 625825 | 2021-11-01 06:14:42 | 44501.260208 | Lobby IN |
| Terry McNeil | 255103 | 2021-11-01 06:18:21 | 44501.262743 | Office |
| Ronald McDonald | 201202 | 2021-11-01 06:23:47 | 44501.266516 | Lobby IN |
| Ronald McDonald | 201202 | 2021-11-01 06:25:10 | 44501.267476 | Office |
| Jerry Maguire | 561390 | 2021-11-01 06:26:16 | 44501.268240 | Lobby IN |
| Cheryl Gates | 111234 | 2021-11-01 06:27:34 | 44501.269143 | Lobby IN |
| Harmony Song | 111234 | 2021-11-01 06:28:45 | 44501.269965 | Controlled OUT |
| Harmony Song | 111555 | 2021-11-01 06:29:27 | 44501.270451 | Lobby OUT |
| Harmony Song | 111555 | 2021-11-01 06:31:03 | 44501.271562 | Lobby IN |
| John Smith | 552510 | 2021-11-01 06:31:07 | 44501.271608 | Controlled IN |
| Franklin Stevens | 551625 | 2021-11-01 06:31:40 | 44501.271990 | Lobby IN |
| Terrance Covington | 625825 | 2021-11-01 06:32:25 | 44501.272511 | Controlled IN |
| Ronald McDonald | 201202 | 2021-11-01 06:33:55 | 44501.273553 | Controlled IN |
| Harmony Song | 111555 | 2021-11-01 06:36:10 | 44501.275115 | Controlled IN |
| Cheryl Gates | 111234 | 2021-11-01 06:36:28 | 44501.275324 | Controlled IN |
| Donna Matthews | 571050 | 2021-11-01 06:36:49 | 44501.275567 | Controlled IN |

**ANSWER**

Here is a table of example results based on the accepted answer below (posted here for formatting), with columns indicated to match the answer formula.

| **G** | **H** | **I** | **K** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Lookup Date** | **Lookup Time** | **Harmony Song** | **John Smith** |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:28 | Not Present | Not Present |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:29 | 44501.269965 | Not Present |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:30 | 44501.269965 | Not Present |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:31 | 44501.269965 | Not Present |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:32 | 44501.269965 | 44501.271608 |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:33 | 44501.269965 | 44501.271608 |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:34 | 44501.269965 | 44501.271608 |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:35 | 44501.269965 | 44501.271608 |

Comment: It would help if you would mock up a small table (only include what is needed) of test data and show the inputs and expected outputs of that small test data set.  Please do this as a mark down table that we can copy paste.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I will create a sample set of data.  But, I don't ask many questions here, can you please describe exactly what you mean/expect when you ask for a "mark down table"?

Comment: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: I don't see `Harmony Song on 2021-11-01 at 6:45` in the data?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, yes, that is the dilemma.  The search will be for a specific time and it needs to find the next-closest time (since a person entering/leaving a place is always variable).

Comment: and we always skip the lobby?  Or is that specific to test 2?

Comment: Its simple then use this formula: `=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(2,1/((G2=A:A)*((H2+I2)>=C:C)),1))`

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, always skip the Lobby (and/or Office).  The only data needed is the IN/OUT of the Controlled space.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya This gets me SO CLOSE!  Your formula is solving the problem of finding the next closest time for a specific person.  The last thing I need to do is skip the lines that are not the Controlled IN/OUT.

Comment: @MatthewSechrist is it working on your end? Can you confirm?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I have added the formula updates into my actual data and so far it's still not skipping the undesired rows.  However, I am currently unable to see the images you posted that may help.  My company's security policy is preventing the images.

Comment: Oh okay, this is the formula: `=INDEX($D:$E,MATCH(2,1/(($G2=$A:$A)*(($H2+$I2)>=$C:$C)*($E:$E<>"Lobby OUT")*($E:$E<>"Lobby IN")*($E:$E<>"Office")),1),COLUMN(A1))` where `G1` --> `Harmony Song` , `H1` --> `11/1/2021` and `E1` you can enter either `6:30:00` or `6:45:00` also the formula need to be entered using `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya What is the basis of the lookup in INDEX changing from D:D to D:E?  Is it related to the COLUMN(A1) at the end?  What is COLUMN(A1) looking for and then sending into INDEX?

Comment: `Column D` refers to `Badge Time` while `Column E` refers to `Locations` so when you drag right the `COLUMN(A1)` changes to `COLUMN(B1)` i.e. it is changing from 1 to 2 where 1 is my first column and 2 is my second column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution: Screenshot shown below for `Example One`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G4</kbd>

```
=INDEX(D:E,MATCH(2,1/((G2=A:A)*((H2+I2)>=C:C)),1),COLUMN(A1))
```

---

Note since its an array formula so while exiting the editing mode hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

Updated as mentioned in comments by **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir. Instead of using `{1,2}` use the one updated to drag over.

---

Screenshot shown below for `Example TWO`

[image]

---

Since you need to exclude the `Office` , `Lobby IN` & `Lobby OUT` use the following formula:

```
=INDEX($D:$E,
  MATCH(2,1/(($G2=$A:$A)*(($H2+$I2)>=$C:$C)*($E:$E<>"Lobby OUT")*($E:$E<>"Lobby IN")*($E:$E<>"Office")),1),
  COLUMN(A1))
```

---

Comment: This works!  I did make some changes based on the arrangement of the results table, which I will post as well.  Here is the final version of the formula based on the above answer:

`=IFNA(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH(2,1/((I$2=$A:$A)*(($G3+$H3)>=$C:$C)*($E:$E<>"Lobby IN")*($E:$E<>"Lobby OUT")*($E:$E<>"Office")),1)),"Not Present")`

Comment: |    **G**   | **H** |     **I**    |     **K**    |
|:----------:|:-----:|:------------:|:------------:|
| Date       | Time  | Harmony Song | John Smith   |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:28 | Not Present  | Not Present  |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:29 | 44501.269965 | Not Present  |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:30 | 44501.269965 | Not Present  |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:31 | 44501.269965 | Not Present  |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:32 | 44501.269965 | 44501.271608 |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:33 | 44501.269965 | 44501.271608 |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:34 | 44501.269965 | 44501.271608 |
| 2021-11-01 | 06:35 | 44501.269965 | 44501.271608 |